# Jquery - GET url value and store in a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I would like to GET the value from my url and store it in a variable the to use it in my sql query as a where statement. My admin_id is good, but the $x is not working.

here is what I got.

The URL http://localhost/ict138final/admin/Aviewrecords.php?edit=2

The Query

```
  $id=$_POST['admin_id'];
  $x=$_POST['edit'];

  $query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM passed_deliverable WHERE deliverable_id={$id} && user_id={$x} ");



 function Delete() {
  window.location.reload();
  lol = $('#wee').text();
  var bayotmarkyu = "<?php  echo $_GET['edit'];  ?>"; 
     $.ajax({   
       type:'POST',
       url:'Adeletedeliverable.php',
       data: {admin_id:lol,edit:bayotmarkyu},
       success: function(data) {
        }
        });
 }
```

Comment: `{$id}` ... `{x}` - one identifier has a $ , the other does not.... And GET!=POST

Comment: If you want GET, then why do you use POST?  anyway, you should also filter, check, sanitize your user input before using it in a query.

Comment: A bit off topic may be, but you are just asking to be hacked. You should filter user input and use prepared statements. Additionally, mysql is deprecated, so use PDO instead.

Comment: `$("[name='admin_id']").val("'DROP TABLE passed_deliverable");` may be a little bit dangerous in your code.Please use safer mysql_* prototypes, like mysqli or PDO, your code is actually exposed to **sql injections**

Comment: i used GET because the value came from my URL, I used POST because the other value came from a table row. @VolkerK

Comment: i used GET because the value came from my URL, I used POST because the other value came from a table row. @lxer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to assign `admin_id` & `edit` using `$_POST` because you send `AJAX` call using POST method.

```
  //on Adeletedeliverable.php file
  print_r($_POST); //only for debug before assign
  $id=$_POST['admin_id'];
  $x=$_POST['edit'];

  $query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM passed_deliverable WHERE deliverable_id={$id} && user_id={$x} ");
  die(json_encode(array('status'=>'success')));


//On javascript funciton(Aviewrecords.php),so just $_GET['edit'];
 function Delete() {
  window.location.reload();
  lol = $('#wee').text();
  var bayotmarkyu = "<?php  echo $_GET['edit'];  ?>"; 
     $.ajax({   
       type:'POST',  // see your ajax call method carefully
       url:'Adeletedeliverable.php',
       data: {admin_id:lol,edit:bayotmarkyu},
       success: function(data) {
        alert(data.status);
        }
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your calling the "x" variable wrong.
Should be $x

and your get should be a post

Answer (score 1):

U have to use $_GET instead of $_POST than.

```
$x=$_GET['edit'];
```

Comment: i didn't use $_GET because in my TYPE before the link is says POST